# Meteor's HTTP 'GET' request does not get XML file

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am working on a research project at my university using the WeatherHawk 916 Wireless Weather Station and using the IP Module connected to it so that it makes the weather data available on campus' network.

To access the data, you have to type an IP Address in a web browser and the data appears as follows: [Weather Station Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbi66.png). The IP Module's server also offers the data as XML (which is what I am interested in so that I can get it using Meteor's HTTP 'GET' and parse it). If you click on "Get Public Table XML", this page appears: [XML Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n81rJ.png).

If I do the Meteor 'GET' HTTP request on the main page, which is just '10.181.160.100', I get the whole HTML page back with no problem, which is good. However, if I try to get the XML from '10.181.160.100/get_public_tbl.cgi?A=1', i get the following error:

```
I20160620-17:41:11.662(-4)? Exception while invoking method 'xmlDemo' Error:    Parse Error
I20160620-17:41:11.833(-4)?     at Object.Future.wait   (/Users/melkisespinal/.meteor/packages/meteor-   tool/.1.3.3_1.ajs0iq++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-  os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:449:15)
I20160620-17:41:11.834(-4)?     at Object.call  (packages/meteor/helpers.js:119:1)
I20160620-17:41:11.834(-4)?     at [object Object].xmlDemo (imports/api/main.js:6:21)
I20160620-17:41:11.834(-4)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1704:12)
I20160620-17:41:11.834(-4)?     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:711:19
I20160620-17:41:11.835(-4)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20160620-17:41:11.835(-4)?     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:709:40
I20160620-17:41:11.835(-4)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20160620-17:41:11.835(-4)?     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:707:46
I20160620-17:41:11.836(-4)?     at tryCallTwo (/Users/melkisespinal/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.7.2.71gs7j++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)
I20160620-17:41:11.836(-4)?     - - - - -
I20160620-17:41:11.836(-4)?     at Socket.socketOnData (http.js:1639:20)
I20160620-17:41:11.837(-4)?     at TCP.onread (net.js:528:27)
```

I was discussing the issue with my faculty advisor and he had the same problem in Java using HTTP Request. He used Firefox's 'Web Developer' tool and saw the Network incoming and outgoing files. The main website returned a status code of 200, which is good, but the one with the XML did not have a header file apparently (so no status code). We said that maybe this was the problem. So instead, he tried using a Socket and then he used a 'GET' request on a PrintWriter using the Socket's InputStream and it worked perfectly. He got the XML back. Now, I don't know if Socket programming is available in Meteor (server-side) / JavaScript.

Here is the code I have for the HTTP call (and fails), which is synchronous for now:

```
'xmlDemo':function(){
    var result = HTTP.call('GET', 'http://10.181.160.100/get_public_tbl.cgi?A=1',
        {});
    if(result.statusCode == 200){
        return result.content;
    }
    else{
        console.log("Response issue: ", result.statusCode);
        throw new Meteor.Error(result.statusCode, result.error);
    }
}
```

If I just do 10.181.160.100/ instead of the current link, it returns back data and it prints to the console (data is undefined if you try to print with the link of the XML file).

So I guess the question is if there is any way we can do Socket Programming to deal with this or anyone knows any other Meteor package that I can add and maybe help me deal with this problem. Thanks in advance.

**Update 1**

Here's the cURL information gotten from Chrome Network feature as requested:

```
curl http://10.181.160.100/get_public_tbl.cgi?A=1'
-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' 
-H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6' 
-H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' 
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36' 
-H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' 
-H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' 
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' 
--compressed
```

Also, I surrounded the code in a try and catch and I got the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
I20160622-20:57:38.918(-4)?     at [object Object].xmlDemo  (imports/api/main.js:27:6)
I20160622-20:57:38.918(-4)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1704:12)
I20160622-20:57:38.918(-4)?     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:711:19
I20160622-20:57:38.919(-4)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20160622-20:57:38.919(-4)?     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:709:40
I20160622-20:57:38.919(-4)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20160622-20:57:38.919(-4)?     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:707:46
I20160622-20:57:38.920(-4)?     at tryCallTwo (/Users/melkisespinal/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.7.2.71gs7j++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)
I20160622-20:57:38.920(-4)?     at doResolve (/Users/melkisespinal/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.7.2.71gs7j++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:200:13)
I20160622-20:57:38.920(-4)?     at new Promise (/Users/melkisespinal/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.7.2.71gs7j++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:66:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer changed. See history for previous (incorrect) attempt.

Try changing your code to do this...

```
var result = HTTP.call(
        'GET',
        'http://10.181.160.100/get_public_tbl.cgi',
        {'query': '?A=1'},
        function(error, result) {
    if(error) {
        // Failed hideously
    } else {
        // Got a response
        if(result.statusCode == 200){
            // Was OK
            return result.content;
        } else {
            // Was something other than a 200 OK
            console.log("Response issue: ", result.statusCode);
            throw new Meteor.Error(result.statusCode, result.error);
        }   
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I updated the post with the response I got. I hope it helps. Also I did "copy response headers" and i got this back: 'HTTP/0.9 200 OK' and you mentioned HTTP/1.1. I don't know if this matters, but there it is anyways.

Comment: New error reported in the original post when I surrounded the HTTP Request in a try and catch block.

Comment: @melkis_espinal Sorry, I've been buried in work recently and haven't been able to revisit.  I don't use meteor but the [manual implies](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/using-the-http-package/#tmc-get-requests) you're calling it wrong...  Note that it uses a callback mechanism for when the request completes (the anonymous `function(error, response) ` and its body are both part of the method call to HTTP, not executed immediately afterwards). Your approach would work if the call were blocking but it looks like it's asynchronous.

Comment: Don't worry and thanks for taking the time. So I did try it as asynchronous (with function(error,response))and I get the same error. I strongly believe that the response I get has no header information because the error says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
". @Basic

Comment: @melkis_espinal That error is javascript telling you that the response object is null. That may be because the server is sending a dodgy response, but the error doesn't say that for certain. Read it slightly differently... "undefined" doesn't have a property called statusCode (which makes sense, undefined doesn't have any properties). You're doing `response.statusCode` thus response is undefined. You can prove it by doing `console.log(response);` Alternatively, put a breakpoint just inside the callback and see what the response object looks like.

Comment: No success with the code you suggested. I get 'I20160624-14:53:44.541(-4)? { [Error: Parse Error] bytesParsed: 0, code: 'HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT' }' @Basic